# Python CEF and Chrome communication using BroadcastChannel

Tags: python, chromium-embedded, broadcast-channel

I have two html pages in my application. Both the pages will open in separate browser windows out of which one will be operator facing and another will be customer facing. Main page (operator facing) send Broadcast Messages using [BroadcastChannel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) and secondary page keeps displaying updates, it received.
This works fine. 
I am trying to create the Python CEF application that loads the customer facing page. Pages loads but two pages can not communicate now.

Am I trying to something which is not supported by CEF or by BoradcastChannel?

Comment: Have you tested your code in Google Chrome? Currently cefpython embeds Chrome v57, so you should check if that Chrome version supports all the functionality you need. There is a new cefpython v66 release coming in a few days.

Comment: Yes I did test in chrome and it works. When I lode same page in CEF then it does not. According to the BroadcastChannel API documentation, it is supported in Chrome v57 too.